# Issue updating TypeScript React functional component with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I have the following interface:

```
interface LinkIconProps {
    href: string;
}
```

And the following functional component signiture:

```
const LinkIcon: FunctionComponent<LinkIconProps> = ({href, children}) => {...}
```

This works fine, but the issue comes when I try to `connect()` the component with Redux, I am not handling the types correctly it seems. My reducer provides a single value `darkModeOn`, so I updated my interface like this:

```
interface LinkIconProps {
    href: string;
    darkModeOn: boolean;
}
```

And my component signature like this:

```
const LinkIcon: FunctionComponent<LinkIconProps> = ({href, darkModeOn, children}) => {...}
```

But now I get the error:

```
Type '{ children: Element; href: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<LinkIconProps, "href" | "darkModeOn">'.
  Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<LinkIconProps, "href" | "darkModeOn">'.  TS2322
```

I assume the TypeScript compiler is inferring that `Pick` type somehow, but not sure why. How do I adjust the types for my props so this will work correctly, or is my issue somewhere else?

Comment: I'd try defining `children: React.ReactNode` into the interface.

Comment: When I do that, I get a different error: `Property 'darkModeOn' is missing in type '{ children: Element; href: string; }' but required in type 'Pick<LinkIconProps, "href" | "darkModeOn" | "children">'.  TS2741
`

Comment: hmm not sure why TypeScript compiler is not able to reference the type properly. I am not so familiar with typescript. I always use Flow. Do you get the same error if you re-order the props type definitions? like place `darkModeOn: boolean` first?

Comment: Ordering doesn't appear to have any affect

Comment: I think the props that you are passing in doesn't match the exact interface.  darkModeOn is defined in interface but it is missing in props that are being passed to LinkIconProps component. To confirm that you can make `darkModeOn` optional and check it out

Comment: have you tried passing the props interface to the `mapState` function?